# How can I use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in an .NET Core console app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependency-injection, .net-core, console-application

I have a library that I would like to run on all platforms supported by .NET Core (Xamarin, Windows, Mac).  And to do this I need to have a cross platform DI to handle the platform specific customizations such as storage, security, etc.

All of the examples I've seen for `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` include code for ASP.NET Core.  Does any equivalent / supported scenario exist for a console app?

Alternatively (ideally) I would like the DI framework used for the console to work for ASP.NET Core, Xamarin, and Win32

**Error Example**

I'm using [this code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx) as the basis for my .NET Core application. It appears that [ServiceCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx) should be public, but when I use Xamarin on the Mac the default implementation of `IServiceCollection` (ServiceCollection) is missing:

[image]

Comment: Add the NuGet packages. Simple.

Comment: It already supports NETStandard 2.0, .NETCoreApp 2.0, NetFramework 4.61, so as John's comment stated, just add it...

Comment: @SushiHangover - I posted detail on the issue

Comment: @TLDR Make sure that you are using the 3.0 preview version, that should solve your problem

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use it basically like so:

Install nuget `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Then in Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton<WhateverType>(new WhateverType());

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();


            serviceProvider.GetService<WhateverType>().DoWork();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You do not need to write the DoWork() method.

Comment: serviceProvider should be wrapped into `using` block to be properly disposed

Comment: @Stritof you do understand this is in the console app, and once `DoWork()` exits, the whole app exits, including the entire dotnet runtime?

Comment: @zaitsman sure, in this example totally not required. But generally if service provider is left undisposed it might not dispose the objects it created. That would be the case if you use several service providers or lifetime of service provider is not the same as application lifetime. My comment is general remark for using DI in console/desktop apps.

Answer (score -11):

**Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection links intro**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/june/essential-net-dependency-injection-with-net-core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

**Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection examples**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddSingleton<WhateverType>(new WhateverType());
        services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
        services.AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>();  

        services.AddInstance<ILoggerFactory>(new Logging.LoggerFactory());
        ILoggingFactory loggingFactor = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
        ILoggingFactory loggingFactor2 = services.GetService<ILoggingFactory>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();                     
        serviceProvider.GetService<WhateverType>().DoWork();
    }
}
```

### **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection examples**

```
public interface IOperation
{
    Guid OperationId { get; }
}

public interface IOperationTransient : IOperation
{
}

public interface IOperationScoped : IOperation
{
}

public interface IOperationSingleton : IOperation
{
}

public interface IOperationSingletonInstance : IOperation
{
}




public class Operation : IOperationTransient, 
    IOperationScoped, 
    IOperationSingleton, 
    IOperationSingletonInstance
{
    public Operation() : this(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
    }

    public Operation(Guid id)
    {
        OperationId = id;
    }

    public Guid OperationId { get; private set; }
}





public class OperationService
{
    public OperationService(
        IOperationTransient transientOperation,
        IOperationScoped scopedOperation,
        IOperationSingleton singletonOperation,
        IOperationSingletonInstance instanceOperation)
    {
        TransientOperation = transientOperation;
        ScopedOperation = scopedOperation;
        SingletonOperation = singletonOperation;
        SingletonInstanceOperation = instanceOperation;
    }

    public IOperationTransient TransientOperation { get; }
    public IOperationScoped ScopedOperation { get; }
    public IOperationSingleton SingletonOperation { get; }
    public IOperationSingletonInstance SingletonInstanceOperation { get; }
}



public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
    services.AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>();
    services.AddScoped<IOperationScoped, Operation>();
    services.AddSingleton<IOperationSingleton, Operation>();
    services.AddSingleton<IOperationSingletonInstance>(new Operation(Guid.Empty));

    // OperationService depends on each of the other Operation types.
    services.AddTransient<OperationService, OperationService>();
}



public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;

    public IndexModel(
        IMyDependency myDependency, 
        OperationService operationService,
        IOperationTransient transientOperation,
        IOperationScoped scopedOperation,
        IOperationSingleton singletonOperation,
        IOperationSingletonInstance singletonInstanceOperation)
    {
        _myDependency = myDependency;
        OperationService = operationService;
        TransientOperation = transientOperation;
        ScopedOperation = scopedOperation;
        SingletonOperation = singletonOperation;
        SingletonInstanceOperation = singletonInstanceOperation;
    }

    public OperationService OperationService { get; }
    public IOperationTransient TransientOperation { get; }
    public IOperationScoped ScopedOperation { get; }
    public IOperationSingleton SingletonOperation { get; }
    public IOperationSingletonInstance SingletonInstanceOperation { get; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        await _myDependency.WriteMessage(
            "IndexModel.OnGetAsync created this message.");
    }
}


using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                var serviceContext = services.GetRequiredService<MyScopedService>();
                // Use the context here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred.");
            }
        }

        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}



------------
public class Host
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
    Application application = new Application(serviceCollection);
    // Run
    // ...
  }
  static private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
  {
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new Logging.LoggerFactory();
    serviceCollection.AddInstance<ILoggerFactory>(loggerFactory);
  }
}
public class Application
{
  public IServiceProvider Services { get; set; }
  public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public Application(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
  {
    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
    Services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    Logger = Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>()
            .CreateLogger<Application>();
    Logger.LogInformation("Application created successfully.");
  }
  public void MakePayment(PaymentDetails paymentDetails)
  {
    Logger.LogInformation(
      $"Begin making a payment { paymentDetails }");
    IPaymentService paymentService =
      Services.GetRequiredService<IPaymentService>();
    // ...
  }
  private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
  {
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IPaymentService, PaymentService>();
  }
}
public class PaymentService: IPaymentService
{
  public ILogger Logger { get; }
  public PaymentService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
    Logger = loggerFactory?.CreateLogger<PaymentService>();
    if(Logger == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
    }
    Logger.LogInformation("PaymentService created");
  }
}


--------

IPaymentService paymentService = Services.GetRequiredService<IPaymentService>()
----------

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IOptions<MyOptions> options)
{
    ...
}

--------

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    ...
}

-----------

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;

    public IndexModel(
        IMyDependency myDependency, 
        OperationService operationService,
        IOperationTransient transientOperation,
        IOperationScoped scopedOperation,
        IOperationSingleton singletonOperation,
        IOperationSingletonInstance singletonInstanceOperation)
    {
        _myDependency = myDependency;
        OperationService = operationService;
        TransientOperation = transientOperation;
        ScopedOperation = scopedOperation;
        SingletonOperation = singletonOperation;
        SingletonInstanceOperation = singletonInstanceOperation;
    }

    public OperationService OperationService { get; }
    public IOperationTransient TransientOperation { get; }
    public IOperationScoped ScopedOperation { get; }
    public IOperationSingleton SingletonOperation { get; }
    public IOperationSingletonInstance SingletonInstanceOperation { get; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        await _myDependency.WriteMessage(
            "IndexModel.OnGetAsync created this message.");
    }
}



-----------

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
    services.AddTransient<IOperationTransient, Operation>();
    services.AddScoped<IOperationScoped, Operation>();
    services.AddSingleton<IOperationSingleton, Operation>();
    services.AddSingleton<IOperationSingletonInstance>(new Operation(Guid.Empty));

    // OperationService depends on each of the other Operation types.
    services.AddTransient<OperationService, OperationService>();
}



-----------------

var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddTransient < SauceBearnaise > ();

ServiceProvider container =
 services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);

IServiceScope scope = container.CreateScope();

SauceBearnaise sauce = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService < SauceBearnaise > ();

 ILoggingFactory loggingFactor = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggingFactory>();


var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddTransient < IIngredient, SauceBearnaise > ();

var container = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);

IServiceScope scope = container.CreateScope();

IIngredient sauce = scope.ServiceProvider
 .GetRequiredService < IIngredient > ();



object Create(ControllerContext context);

Type controllerType = context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.AsType();

Type controllerType = context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.AsType();
return scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(controllerType);


services.AddTransient < IIngredient, SauceBearnaise > ();



services.AddTransient < SauceBearnaise > ();
services.AddTransient < IIngredient > (
 c => c.GetRequiredService < SauceBearnaise > ());




services.AddTransient < SauceBearnaise > ();
services.AddTransient < IIngredient > (
 c => c.GetRequiredService < SauceBearnaise > ());




services.AddTransient < SauceBearnaise > ();
services.AddTransient < IIngredient, SauceBearnaise > ();



services.AddSingleton < SauceBearnaise > ();
services.AddSingleton < IIngredient, SauceBearnaise > ();



services.AddTransient < IIngredient, SauceBearnaise > ();
services.AddTransient < ICourse, Course > ();



services.AddTransient < IIngredient, SauceBearnaise > ();
services.AddTransient < IIngredient, Steak > ();



Assembly ingredientsAssembly = typeof(Steak).Assembly;

var ingredientTypes =
 from type in ingredientsAssembly.GetTypes()
where!type.IsAbstract
where typeof(IIngredient).IsAssignableFrom(type)
select type;

foreach(var type in ingredientTypes) {
 services.AddTransient(typeof(IIngredient), type);
}





Assembly ingredientsAssembly = typeof(Steak).Assembly;

var ingredientTypes =
 from type in ingredientsAssembly.GetTypes()
where!type.IsAbstract
where typeof(IIngredient).IsAssignableFrom(type)
where type.Name.StartsWith("Sauce")
select type;

foreach(var type in ingredientTypes) {
 services.AddTransient(typeof(IIngredient), type);
}






Assembly policiesAssembly = typeof(DiscountPolicy).Assembly;

var policyTypes =
 from type in policiesAssembly.GetTypes()
where type.Name.EndsWith("Policy")
select type;

foreach(var type in policyTypes) {
 services.AddTransient(type.BaseType, type);
}




public interface ICommandService < TCommand > {
 void Execute(TCommand command);
}



public class AdjustInventoryService: ICommandService < AdjustInventory > {
 private readonly IInventoryRepository repository;

 public AdjustInventoryService(IInventoryRepository repository) {
  this.repository = repository;
 }

 public void Execute(AdjustInventory command) {
  var productId = command.ProductId;

  ...
 }
}




Assembly assembly = typeof(AdjustInventoryService).Assembly;

var mappings =
 from type in assembly.GetTypes()
where!type.IsAbstract
where!type.IsGenericType
from i in type.GetInterfaces()
where i.IsGenericType
where i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
 typeof(ICommandService < > )
select new {
 service = i, type
};

foreach(var mapping in mappings) {
 services.AddTransient(
  mapping.service,
  mapping.type);
}




services.AddSingleton < SauceBearnaise > ();



services.AddSingleton < IIngredient, SauceBearnaise > ();




using(IServiceScope scope = container.CreateScope()) {
 IMeal meal = scope.ServiceProvider
  .GetRequiredService < IMeal > ();

 meal.Consume();

}




services.AddScoped < IIngredient, SauceBearnaise > ();




container.Dispose();


public enum Spiciness {
 Mild,
 Medium,
 Hot
}



services.AddSingleton(
 typeof(Spiciness), Spiciness.Medium);

services.AddTransient < ICourse, ChiliConCarne > ();



public class Flavoring {
 public readonly Spiciness Spiciness;
 public readonly bool ExtraSalty;

 public Flavoring(Spiciness spiciness, bool extraSalty) {
  this.Spiciness = spiciness;
  this.ExtraSalty = extraSalty;
 }
}




var flavoring = new Flavoring(Spiciness.Medium, extraSalty: true);
services.AddSingleton < Flavoring > (flavoring);

container.AddTransient < ICourse, ChiliConCarne > ();




services.AddTransient < ICourse > (c => new ChiliConCarne(Spiciness.Hot));



public static IServiceCollection AddTransient < TService > (
 this IServiceCollection services,
 Func < IServiceProvider, TService > implementationFactory)
where TService: class;




internal JunkFood(string name)



public static class JunkFoodFactory {
 public static JunkFood Create(string name) {
  return new JunkFood(name);
 }
}


public ChiliConCarne(Spiciness spiciness)

public enum Spiciness {
 Mild,
 Medium,
 Hot
}



services.AddSingleton(
 typeof(Spiciness), Spiciness.Medium);

services.AddTransient < ICourse, ChiliConCarne > ();



public class Flavoring {
 public readonly Spiciness Spiciness;
 public readonly bool ExtraSalty;

 public Flavoring(Spiciness spiciness, bool extraSalty) {
  this.Spiciness = spiciness;
  this.ExtraSalty = extraSalty;
 }
}




var flavoring = new Flavoring(Spiciness.Medium, extraSalty: true);
services.AddSingleton < Flavoring > (flavoring);

container.AddTransient < ICourse, ChiliConCarne > ();





services.AddTransient < ICourse > (c => new ChiliConCarne(Spiciness.Hot));




public static IServiceCollection AddTransient < TService > (
 this IServiceCollection services,
 Func < IServiceProvider, TService > implementationFactory)
where TService: class;




internal JunkFood(string name)




public static class JunkFoodFactory {
 public static JunkFood Create(string name) {
  return new JunkFood(name);
 }
}








services.AddTransient < IMeal > (c => JunkFoodFactory.Create("chicken meal"));




services.AddTransient < IIngredient, SauceBearnaise > ();
services.AddTransient < IIngredient, Steak > ();







IEnumerable < IIngredient > ingredients =
 scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices < IIngredient > ();


IEnumerable < IIngredient > ingredients = scope.ServiceProvider
 .GetRequiredService < IEnumerable < IIngredient >> ();



public ThreeCourseMeal(ICourse entrée, ICourse mainCourse, ICourse dessert)







services.AddTransient < IMeal > (c => new ThreeCourseMeal(
 entrée: c.GetRequiredService < Rillettes > (),
 mainCourse: c.GetRequiredService < CordonBleu > (),
 dessert: c.GetRequiredService < CrèmeBrûlée > ()));



public ThreeCourseMeal(
 ICourse entrée,
 ICourse mainCourse,
 ICourse dessert,
 ...
)




services.AddTransient < IMeal > (c =>
 ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance < ThreeCourseMeal > (
  c,
  new object[] {
   c.GetRequiredService < Rillettes > (),
    c.GetRequiredService < CordonBleu > (),
    c.GetRequiredService < MousseAuChocolat > ()
  }));



public static T CreateInstance < T > (
 IServiceProvider provider,
 params object[] parameters);



public Meal(IEnumerable < ICourse > courses)


services.AddTransient < ICourse, Rillettes > ();
services.AddTransient < ICourse, CordonBleu > ();
services.AddTransient < ICourse, MousseAuChocolat > ();

services.AddTransient < IMeal, Meal > ();



services.AddScoped < Rillettes > ();
services.AddTransient < LobsterBisque > ();
services.AddScoped < CordonBleu > ();
services.AddScoped < OssoBuco > ();
services.AddSingleton < MousseAuChocolat > ();
services.AddTransient < CrèmeBrûlée > ();

services.AddTransient < ICourse > (
 c => c.GetRequiredService < Rillettes > ());
services.AddTransient < ICourse(
 c => c.GetRequiredService < LobsterBisque > ());
services.AddTransient < ICourse > (
 c => c.GetRequiredService < CordonBleu > ());
services.AddTransient < ICourse(
 c => c.GetRequiredService < OssoBuco > ());
services.AddTransient < ICourse > (
 c => c.GetRequiredService < MousseAuChocolat > ());
services.AddTransient < ICourse(
 c => c.GetRequiredService < CrèmeBrûlée > ());

services.AddTransient < IMeal > (c = new Meal(
 new ICourse[] {
  c.GetRequiredService < Rillettes > (),
   c.GetRequiredService < CordonBleu > (),
   c.GetRequiredService < MousseAuChocolat > ()
 }));






services.AddTransient < IIngredient > (c =>
 ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance < Breading > (
  c,
  ActivatorUtilities
  .CreateInstance < VealCutlet > (c)));



services.AddTransient < IIngredient > (c =>
 ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance < Breading > (
  c,
  ActivatorUtilities
  .CreateInstance < HamCheeseGarlic > (
   c,
   ActivatorUtilities
   .CreateInstance < VealCutlet > (c))));







new Breading(
 new HamCheeseGarlic(
  new VealCutlet()));



Assembly assembly = typeof(AdjustInventoryService).Assembly;

var mappings =
 from type in assembly.GetTypes()
where!type.IsAbstract
where!type.IsGenericType
from i in type.GetInterfaces()
where i.IsGenericType
where i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
 typeof(ICommandService < > )
select new {
 service = i, implementation = type
};

foreach(var mapping in mappings) {
 Type commandType =
  mapping.service.GetGenericArguments()[0];

 Type secureDecoratoryType =
  typeof(SecureCommandServiceDecorator < > )
  .MakeGenericType(commandType);
 Type transactionDecoratorType =
  typeof(TransactionCommandServiceDecorator < > )
  .MakeGenericType(commandType);
 Type auditingDecoratorType =
  typeof(AuditingCommandServiceDecorator < > )
  .MakeGenericType(commandType);

 services.AddTransient(mapping.service, c =>
  ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(
   c,
   secureDecoratoryType,
   ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(
    c,
    transactionDecoratorType,
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(
     c,
     auditingDecoratorType,
     ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(
      c,
      mapping.implementation)))));
}







public class CompositeNotificationService: INotificationService {
 private readonly IEnumerable < INotificationService > services;

 public CompositeNotificationService(
  IEnumerable < INotificationService > services) {
  this.services = services;
 }

 public void OrderApproved(Order order) {
  foreach(INotificationService service in this.services) {
   service.OrderApproved(order);
  }
 }
}




services.AddTransient < OrderApprovedReceiptSender > ();
services.AddTransient < AccountingNotifier > ();
services.AddTransient < OrderFulfillment > ();

services.AddTransient < INotificationService > (c =>
 new CompositeNotificationService(
  new INotificationService[] {
   c.GetRequiredService < OrderApprovedReceiptSender > (),
    c.GetRequiredService < AccountingNotifier > (),
    c.GetRequiredService < OrderFulfillment > (),
  }));




Assembly assembly = typeof(OrderFulfillment).Assembly;

Type[] types = (
  from type in assembly.GetTypes() where!type.IsAbstract where typeof(INotificationService).IsAssignableFrom(type) select type)
 .ToArray();

foreach(Type type in types) {
 services.AddTransient(type);
}

services.AddTransient < INotificationService > (c =>
 new CompositeNotificationService(
  types.Select(t =>
   (INotificationService) c.GetRequiredService(t))
  .ToArray()));





Type[] types = (
  from type in assembly.GetTypes() where!type.IsAbstract where typeof(INotificationService)
  .IsAssignableFrom(type) where type != typeof(CompositeNotificationService) select type)
 .ToArray();




Type[] types = (
  from type in assembly.GetTypes() where!type.IsAbstract where typeof(INotificationService).IsAssignableFrom(type) where type != typeof(CompositeNotificationService) where type => !IsDecoratorFor < INotificationService > (type) select type)
 .ToArray();






private static bool IsDecoratorFor < T > (Type type) {
 return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type) &&
  type.GetConstructors()[0].GetParameters()
  .Any(p => p.ParameterType == typeof(T));
}





public class CompositeSettings {
 public Type[] AllHandlerTypes {
  get;
  set;
 }
}

public class CompositeEventHandler < TEvent >
 : IEventHandler < TEvent > {
  private readonly IServiceProvider provider;
  private readonly CompositeSettings settings;

  public CompositeEventHandler(
   IServiceProvider provider,
   CompositeSettings settings) {
   this.provider = provider;
   this.settings = settings;
  }

  public void Handle(TEvent e) {
   foreach(var handler in this.GetHandlers()) {
    handler.Handle(e);
   }
  }

  IEnumerable < IEventHandler < TEvent >> GetHandlers() {
   return
   from type in this.settings.AllHandlerTypes
   where typeof(IEventHandler < TEvent > )
   .IsAssignableFrom(type)
   select(IEventHandler < TEvent > )
   ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(
    this.provider, type);
  }
 }






var handlerTypes =
 from type in assembly.GetTypes()
where!type.IsAbstract
where!type.IsGenericType
let serviceTypes = type.GetInterfaces()
 .Where(i => i.IsGenericType &&
  i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
  typeof(IEventHandler < > ))
where serviceTypes.Any()
select type;

services.AddSingleton(new CompositeSettings {
 AllHandlerTypes = handlerTypes.ToArray()
});

services.AddTransient(
 typeof(IEventHandler < > ),
 typeof(CompositeEventHandler < > ));
```