# How can I use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in an UNO Platform app

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, uno-platform

I am new to [UNO Platform](https://platform.uno/) and I am trying to develop my first application with this framework. I would like to use a DI toolkit also so I chose `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` that should be compliant with this Platform.

By the way, I cannot understand how can I inject dependencies to my ViewModels.
I red this post:
[How can I use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in an .NET Core console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825155/how-can-i-use-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-in-an-net-core-console-a) and this is my approach:

**App.xaml.cs**:

```
    public App()
    {
        ConfigureFilters(global::Uno.Extensions.LogExtensionPoint.AmbientLoggerFactory);

        var services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IMessageBroker, MessageBroker>();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }
```

where `IMessageBroker` and `MessageBroker` are the interface and the implementation of my class I would like to handle with DI.
Then on my ViewModel I do:

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
public MainPageViewModel(IMessageBroker broker)
{
     // some code
}
```

So far, so good.

For MVVM toolkit, I chose [MVVM helpers](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers).
If I understood correctly, this MVVM toolkit does not provide any convention to attach View to ViewModel so I should do it manually:

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // How can I get a reference to ServiceProvider for calling GetService
        var broker = serviceProvider.GetService<IMessageBroker>()

        this.DataContext = new MainPageViewModel(broker);
    }
}
```

How can I get a reference here to `ServiceProvider` for calling `GetService<IMessageBroker>()`?

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way you could do is having a static class ServiceLocator, which is initialized only from the beginning. This class exposes a readonly ServiceProvider, and you can call it to get the thing you register.

You may read somewhere else, or someone else here may comment this is `anti-pattern`, which is generally out of context. Depending on what you are trying to do and how your solution is structured, this service locator pattern can be totally fine.

here is a sample project you can use for reference
https://github.com/weitzhandler/UnoRx/tree/f2a0771e6a513863108e58ac7087078f39f7e3ed

an alternative will be, writing a viewmodel locator, which automatically resolves all dependencies through your view. This, however, may or may not overkill your use case.

finally, my personal flavor, having a shell project that depends on auto discovery and auto resolving; and each discovered smaller projects will internally depends on either service locator or function compositions